# Customising the API mapping for admin-on-rest, need a function to change “id” key to “userid” for example

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am using admin-on-rest to build an admin panel for my webapp.

From the documentation at https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/ i did not find a way to change the identifier of the record of the rest API. it seems that the filed is always 'id'

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in a custom `restClient` (see https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html). For instance, if the API returns records with an `_id` identifier:

```
const convertHTTPResponseToREST = (response, type, resource, params) => {
    const { headers, json } = response;
    switch (type) {
    case GET_LIST:
        return {
            data: json.map(x => { ...x, id: x._id } ),
            total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
        };
    case UPDATE:
    case DELETE:
    case GET_ONE:
       return { ...json, id: json._id }; 
    case CREATE:
        return { ...params.data, id: json._id };
    default:
        return json;
    }
};
```

By the way, please don't double post here and [in the admin-on-rest issue tracker](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/373), this gives more work to the maintainers.